# Remove and replace ubuntu

Tags: boot, system-installation, bios

the ultimate goal is to remove ubuntu and load my old factory reset cd to get windows 7 loaded up. heres the story, i messed up my original windows7 OS after a partitioning mistake. i use the factory reset cd to fix it and alter my bios to load the cd drive firts (Bios button IS f10, DO NOT ARGUE!). i fix the computer but decide i want to try a linux OS. so i install ubuntu. but since steam and wine (even with some attempted fixes) won't work i decide i want to go pack to windows 7.

heres the problem.

i press the Bios button at startup (*IS* f10) but no bios menu, just continuing to ubuntu. will not load ANY of my Bootables (CD or USB). i try running without a hard drive plugged in (stupid or not stupid?) and nothing loads up. i think if i wipe the primary drive it will work but i find no way of doing that without BIOS or bootable drives. the only way to do that i have available is wiping from the primary drive (like cleaning the floor your standing on i guess)

All i really know is it worked fine *before* ubuntu and that my BIOS button is f10

Comment: Try the other keys at random.  Like f2 f6 f8 and escape.  But r them all  on a reboot marathon.  F10 seems like boot order menu, but maybe you are right.  Seems like something you did in bios.  Call tech support to get bios working.  Google your model number and bios setup.  Lastly, if you are going to wipe and install and you are register in windows, make a windows 10 with november update (or higher) usb install.  Google that too.

Answer (score 0):

realised what was happening. this was made out of a computer that was dissassembled (i was bored ok) and reassambeled without its laptop screen ( using a monitor) but the motherboard was still trying to output some visuals to that laptop screen which is why most of my programs like wine and steam wont show but will show in dash bar.

with this considered ill give ubuntu another chance

p.s. bios button is f2 *grumpy mumble*

Comment: sorry i didnt mention the reassambling bit, i thought it was irrelavant to the problem (sure as !#$@ was wrong)